# PHP How to use preg replace instead of ereg replace?

Tags: php, regex

Since ereg replace is depreciated, i would like to know how to use preg instead. Here is my code and i need to replace { } tags.

```
$template = ereg_replace('{USERNAME}', $info['username'], $template);
    $template = ereg_replace('{EMAIL}', $info['email'], $template);
    $template = ereg_replace('{KEY}', $info['key'], $template);
    $template = ereg_replace('{SITEPATH}','http://somelinkhere.com', $template);
```

It won't work if i just switch it to preg replace.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_replace()`, why not?

Like this, wow:

```
<?php
$template = str_replace('{USERNAME}', $info['username'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{EMAIL}', $info['email'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{KEY}', $info['key'], $template);
$template = str_replace('{SITEPATH}','http://somelinkhere.com', $template);
?>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: @user2802518 so mark it as a solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how ereg_replace work but preg_replace works regular expressions.

If you want to replace "{" and "}"

The correct way will be:

```
$template = preg_replace("/({|})/", "", $template);
// if $template == "asd{asdasd}asda{ds}{{"
// the output will be "asdasdasdasdads"
```

Now, if you would like to replace "{" and "}" only where is something specific inside them you should execute:

```
$user = "whatever";
$template = preg_replace("/{($user)}/", "$0", $template);
// if $template == "asd{whatever}asda{ds}"
// the output will be "asdwhateverasda{ds}"
```

If you want to replace "{" and "}" with something that could be any string with only letters from "a" to "Z"

You should use:

```
$template = preg_replace("/{([a-Z]*)}/", "$0", $template);
// if $template == "asd{whatever}asda{ds}{}{{{}"
// the output will be "asdwhateverasdads{}{{{}"
```

Comment: "works with regex and regular expressions." --- what?

Comment: I tried to explain that preg_replace uses regex module so you have to use regular expressions to make the search.

Comment: What is "regex module"?